# results of mediation isnt in line with compression of the included glmm models

Tags: generalized-linear-model, mediation

I'll begin with my two question and all the related information (description of the research and the data and full output) will follow.

1. When i execute model1 (glmm with random intercept only for subjects): predictor (suppBin) and outcome (DtlsBinUp) and pre-intervention variables, it results with significance . when I carry out model 2: add the mediator (rlctDown) too as a predictor, the association shown in the model1 isn't significant anymore (suppBin-DtlsBinup), and for the mediator and outcome it is (rlctDown-dtlsBinup), with higher coefficient. that should imply for full mediation, meaning there isn't direct effect between the predictor and the outcome, only indirect. but when i the test mediation model (monte carlo method), I gel significant effect for total effect, direct effect and the indirect effect. how can it be that the monte carlo contradicts what shown when substracting model1 from model2? what am i missing?

2.i am having trouble in interpreting the values of the effects estimations in the monte carlo test. I understood the coefficients for the glmm
as log odds that after transforming using exponential function can be understood as odds and may also be expressed as probabilities. but
the estimates in the monte carlo output are much lower than those in the glmm output. so how should they be understood.

following are description and output,
thank you 
uri.

```
********** predictor - outcome


Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) ['glmerMod']
 Family: binomial  ( logit )
Formula: dtlsBinUp ~ suppBin * qu + ageS + gender + (1 | PD)
   Data: hypoTest
Control: glmerControl(tolPwrss = 0.001)

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
 15351.9  15406.1  -7669.0  15337.9    17111 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-0.6655 -0.5281 -0.5140 -0.1889  5.4472 

Random effects:
 Groups Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 PD     (Intercept) 0        0       
Number of obs: 17118, groups:  PD, 200

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) -3.20574    0.14668 -21.856  

********** predictor, mediator - outcome

Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) ['glmerMod']
 Family: binomial  ( logit )
Formula: dtlsBinUp ~ suppBin * qu + rlctDown + ageS + gender + (1 | PD)
   Data: hypoTest
Control: glmerControl(tolPwrss = 0.001)

 AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 


14114.1  14176.0  -7049.0  14098.1    17110 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-1.5239 -0.4638 -0.4552 -0.1487  6.8990 

Random effects:
 Groups Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 PD     (Intercept) 0        0

Number of obs: 17118, groups:  PD, 200

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)

(Intercept) -3.69635    0.15247  -24.24   <2e-16 *
suppBin      0.14896    0.16475    0.90    0.366

qu           2.26040    0.11289   20.02   <2e-16 *
rlctDown     2.06709    0.05947   34.76   <2e-16 ***
ageS        -0.10680    0.10432   -1.02    0.306

gender      -0.02293    0.04360   -0.53    0.599    

suppBin:qu   0.13720    0.17963    0.76    0.445

Signif. codes:  0 ‘’ 0.001 ‘’ 0.01 ‘’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
           (Intr) suppBn qu     rlctDw ageS   gender
suppBin    -0.462

qu         -0.708  0.629

rlctDown   -0.159 -0.088  0.143

ageS       -0.665  0.000 -0.018 -0.005

gender     -0.184  0.008  0.035  0.024  0.066

suppBin:qu  0.426 -0.916 -0.607  0.062  0.005 -0.029

********** predictor, mediator - outcome (function "mediate" from packege "mediation"
```

** script (syntax):

med.out.8.1.2.1

Simulations: 1000

Comment: I have edited this to make it more readable, please revert any edits which change the meaning.